# Maxscript - How do I change the render to texture output directory in 3ds Max 2020?

Tags: maxscript

**Max 2020**

I'm trying to change the default path of the exported render to texture maps.

Here's the code I have for that.

```
fn shakeAndBake theObj pxlSize = (

  local theObj = $
  theObj.iNodeBakeProperties.removeAllBakeElements()
  diffuseColor = Corona_DiffuseColor()
  diffuseColor.outputSzX = diffuseColor.outputSzY = pxlSize
  diffuseColor.fileType = (@"C:\\"+theObj.name+"_diffuse.png")
  diffuseColor.fileName = filenameFromPath diffuseColor.fileType
  diffuseColor.enabled = true
  theObj.INodeBakeProperties.addBakeElement diffuseColor
  select theObj
  render rendertype:#bakeSelected vfb:off progressBar:true outputSize:[pxlSize,pxlSize] cancelled:&wasCanceled quiet:true;

  )
theObject = shakeAndBake theObject 512
```

It keeps outputting the textures to this path:

`C:\Users\user\Documents\3ds Max 2020\sceneassets\images`

I thought that this line of the code would change this:

`diffuseColor.fileType = (@"C:\\"+theObj.name+"_diffuse.png")`

Anyone any idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

*Somehow I have a feeling you still need to pass " outputfile: " parameter to render function*

Sorry for my idiotic non-answer. I will try to redeem myself.
seems that in the `diffuseColor.fileType` you are setting type of bitmap, so if it will be png, bmp etc
`diffuseColor.fileName` should contain whole path with the filename.
Also if you put "@" in front of the string, it becomes verbatim string literal and doesn't need double slashes [Official autodtesk maxscript help, string literals](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_7F17449E_C377_445C_AC15_CD3BA88A975B_htm)

Works perfectly fine if you change it like that:

```
fn shakeAndBake theObj pxlSize = (

  local theObj = $
  theObj.iNodeBakeProperties.removeAllBakeElements()
  diffuseColor = Corona_DiffuseColor()
  diffuseColor.outputSzX = diffuseColor.outputSzY = pxlSize
  diffuseColor.fileType = (@"F:\TEMP\"+theObj.name+"_diffuse.png")
  diffuseColor.fileName = diffuseColor.fileType
  diffuseColor.enabled = true
  theObj.INodeBakeProperties.addBakeElement diffuseColor
  select theObj
  render rendertype:#bakeSelected vfb:off progressBar:true outputSize:[pxlSize,pxlSize] cancelled:&wasCanceled quiet:true;

  )
  theObject = shakeAndBake theObject 512
```